# Pass parameters from mail link to login page of web app asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a web application in asp.net csharp.

i am sending mail to one admin as alert when a user makes a entry into a system.
with this mail one link is also sent that redirects to the login page.

when the admin clicks on the link it redirects to the login page.

but the parameter is not accessable into the system ... the parameter is visible into the url but not able to acces it using Request.querystring, it gives null value.

is there any other way i can access that parameter.

thanks
Kumar

Comment: could you please post here both your query string and the code you are using to read query string?

Comment: string link1 = "http://QATrack/Login.aspx?variable=" + Appendid;

Comment: string id1 = Request.QueryString["variable"]; To access

Comment: why do you have semicolon after variable=? Is it possible for you post the final form of url? i mean the value of link1

Comment: http://IP/QATrack/(S(pm1kpaiikuoq5x5r55tugbif))/Login.aspx?variable=EPL/PRD/0006/11

Answer (score 0):

try using `Request["variable"]`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some sort of URL rewriting active? My guess is while rewriting the url the parameter might be left behind. Please add some more info about your setup.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this
string s = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["variable"];
I try with this "?variable=EPL/PRD/0006/11" and i got the value.